# Build QtDropbox in C++ (Cannot find QLocale)

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to build QtDropbox to use in a project of my own in visual studio. QtDropbox uses Qt of course and I included it into the project (as you can see on the image).

[image: Include and lib]

My problem is that it cannot find `#include <QLocale>`. So what dependency did I forgot?

Comment: Try to add `C:\Qt\5.4\msvc2013_64\include\QtCore` to your `Include Directories` list.

Comment: That is the solution :) Thx If you type it as an awnser then I will put it on resolved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to let your compiler find the mentioned include file you have to extend the list of `Include Directories` in your Visual Studio project's configuration. The mentioned file can be found in `QtCore` sub directory of Qt include files, so you simply need to add `C:\Qt\5.4\msvc2013_64\include\QtCore` path to the list too.